# Eclipse hanging on to port after server stopped

Tags: java, eclipse, multithreading, sockets, serversocket

I have ServerSocket that initialized normal. After some clients connections or some time delay (I dont know what the reason is exacly) and  **server termination**  by `server.close();` I tried to start the server again and it throws the following execption:

```
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.bind0(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(Unknown Source)
at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(Unknown Source)
at network.Server.<init>(Server.java:24)
at network.Server.getServerInstance(Server.java:47)
at gui.MainScreen.<init>(MainScreen.java:66)
at gui.MainScreen.main(MainScreen.java:54)
```

I have verified that:

 The server terminated correctly.

 No other ServerSocket is using this port

I checked in cmd wheter the port is listenning and it is, even though the server is closed.

By the corresponding PID the application that uses this port is Eclipse itself.

 After I restart Eclipse I could start the Server without problems.

What can I do for Eclipse to release the port?

Comment: It's very easy to loose track of running code in eclipse, are you sure that it wasn't your own code running secretly in eclipse? (The red stop button is still available to be pressed) Otherwise, I've not heard about Eclipse openening ports. Do you use special eclipse plugins or so?

Comment: No red button is available (It is gray). I downloaded today the Mars verison in hope it is Eclipse fault and didnt install any plugins